# Loop thru an array and insert into or update a column based on empty values in the column - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, email

I will have user input content(email addresses) that I'll be introducing into a database(MySQL) based on what project those emails are from. I have 1 email table for all of the projects, which aren't that many(about 20), each project will have a separate column. Some emails are going to be removed eventually and some fields in some rows will be marked as empty or null.

Most of the time the emails will come in bulk(so to speak) so I'll have to loop thru an array of emails and for every value, introduce that value into whatever project that email belongs to. So far so good, that's already done.

However, as I said, some emails are going to be removed. I want to replace empty fields with email addresses and if no empty fields are found insert the emails into the column.

Emails will come in bulks so I'll loop thru the array and for every value proceed to execute an insert or update statement depending on the empty fields.

Long story short I have this code:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM table_name 
    CASE 
      WHEN column_name='' OR column_name IS NULL 
      THEN 
      UPDATE SET column_name='new_value' 
      WHERE column_name='' OR column_name IS NULL
      ELSE INSERT INTO table_name(column_name) VALUES ('new_value')
    END
```

Which doesn't work. I'm 100% sure I messed up the syntax somewhere, however the MySQL manual is not much of a help. Some pages suggest using CASE, some suggest using IF.

If somebody could take a look at it and give me some pointers, I'd be very grateful.

I'm using PHP for this.

If anything is unclear in my explanation(I have a habit of doing that), please let me know.

---

Looking at the IF/ELSEIF from MySQL manual:

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

My new and no so improved code should look like this:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM table_name 
IF column_name='' OR column_name IS NULL 
THEN UPDATE SET column_name='new_value' WHERE column_name='' OR column_name IS NULL 
ELSE INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES ('new_value) 
END IF
```

Which of course does not work.

Comment: do you get this error  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Comment: Yes, I know I have an error. Probably not just one. The problem is I can't figure out the right syntax...

Comment: Is it ok to fire 2 different queries i.e one for insert and one for update?

Comment: Due to the nature of the coding the page would have to be refreshed twice to firstly compare what emails are there and secondly to insert the remaining ones that were not introduced in the update. And we all know that hitting that damn submit button twice requires a PHD in rocket science and probably a few years of experience which clearly no normal user has...So no...I mean, yeah, it's doable, but I'd get nailed to a cross and fed to hungry hippos if that were to happen.

Comment: I must say you know lot of phrases .. lol... Will see what i can do

Comment: Scratch that. It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If column_name is a PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE INDEX you can use [INSERT.. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name(column_name) VALUES ('new_value')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE column_name = 'new_value'
```

From the docs:

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an
>   UPDATE of the old row is performed.

Comment: No Primary Key or Unique Index unfortunately... -.-

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense? Think about it. If you want it to do this every single time, maybe you could add the UNIQUE INDEX just for this. Otherwise you will have to go through the table every single time you want to do the INSERT

Comment: It would. A lot. I'm merely a greasy code monkey(not a very good one either). I was told to not modify the tables/column or fire and brimstone will rain from the sky, with baby blood too...

Comment: lol. ok. explain also what columns you want to update then. If you don't have a duplicate key, how do you know which ones are to be updated?

Comment: OK, so there's a very simple form with 2 fields. 1 is project name and the other is the e-mail addresses to be introduced. So by default only 1 column will be updated at a time. As I said, array->emails, yadda yadda. First I'm checking if the either of the emails already exists in that column, if yes then kill the page, if not proceed with a foreach loop with an insert statement for the $key of the array(meaning first email in array). However, if say, the second field is empty, I want that email to go in there(update) if no empty fields, insert in column.

Comment: Well, I kinda solved it. Not the most elegant way, but it will do ->http://pastebin.com/3MLAgGQE -- Scratch that. It does not work.

Comment: Yes. Without having a UNIQUE index that looks like one approach of handling it.

Comment: @user3011538 so you used this link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php to solve your prblem?

Comment: @AshReva: No, just saw the reply. But I remembered the rowCount(); function so, solved it finally. It was a simple if/else ->http://pastebin.com/wiM4UKEW . Basically check if any rows from that column contain empty or null fields, if so update, else insert. And do this for every key of the array. Not the best way to do it, I'll admit.